# Dynamically loading elements in the listView using Restful webservices from MAF application

Tags: rest, listview, web, service, maf

I want to dynamically load the employee list on the amx page in the listview using RESTful webservices from MAF application.And then after selecting one of the items I want to display its corresponding details on the next amx page. I am new to this technology.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried taking one text input parameter and printing its details on the same page using restful web services.

Comment: May we see some relevant code, edited into your question? It is a bit vague at present.

Comment: It will be great if I get the direction to start my work or any useful links. At this point I am not able to sort out from where to start and i have to complete this task within one day.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have the REST APIs ready with you.. In that case, follow this link [MAF tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_json/tut_jdev_maf_json_2.html#DC)

In case you want to make a REST API yourself, you can follow this link :
[MAF tutorials - 2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_jdev_maf_persistance/tut_jdev_maf_persistance.html)

Hope this helps.